# How to add breadcrumb?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, breadcrumbs

How can I add breadcrumb to a page in my attendance module.

I have used the following hook, but it changed the breadcrumb for all pages in other modules also.

```
function attendance_init() {
// set the breadcrumb
$breadcrumb = array();
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
$breadcrumb[] = l('People', 'group/node/'. arg(2) .'/people');
$breadcrumb[] = l('Attendance', 'group/node/'. arg(2) .'/people/attendance');
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);         
}
```

Comment: There's a SO spin off just for Drupal related questions: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to change the breadcrumb for a specific content type nodes, try to use [hook_node_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)()

Here's an example:

```
function attendance_node_view_alter(&$build)
{
    $node = $build['#node'];
    if($build['#view_mode'] == "full" && $node->type == "attendance")
    {
        $breadcrumb = array();
        $breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
        $breadcrumb[] = l('People', 'group/node/'. arg(2) .'/people');
        $breadcrumb[] = l('Attendance', 'group/node/'. arg(2) .'/people/attendance');
        drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
    }
}
```

Hope this works... Muhammad

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your help. I have implement this by some other way.

Comment: Umar next time do you mind posting how you implemented your way of fixing it, instead of accepting an answer? This is usefully because it allow you to explain how you fixed your issue which may in return help future users.